# SQL Parameters with Like Terms in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlparameter

I have a pretty complex query and was fixing my like terms (which I have as a separate db table and load them into my search query), but when I parameterize it, my query gives different results.

So the old query had a like section like so:

```
((v.title = ''BA'') OR (vs.label = ''BA'') OR 
(v.title LIKE ''BA %'') OR (vs.label LIKE ''BA %''))
...
```

And I replaced it with something like this (with parameters):

```
((v.title = @banone) OR (vs.label = @banone) OR 
(v.title LIKE @baright) OR (vs.label LIKE @baright))
...
@banone=N'BA',@baright=N'BA %',
...
```

My parameters get added like so:

```
string key = "ba"; 
string val = "ba";

parameters.Add("@" + key + "none", val);
parameters.Add("@" + key + "right",  val + " %");
```

Are these two queries equal? Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you test if they are equal?

Comment: Are you really setting the variables after the query or is that just how you posted it?

Comment: the snippet is from sql profiler and how the db sees it

Comment: but in theory, shouldn't the above be equal?

Comment: Shouldn't your second parameter be `@baright=N''BA %''` for the `LIKE` to work right?

Comment: i updated to show how the parameters are set

Comment: So I am assuming that you are really using BA(uppercase) for val?

Comment: With the parameters.add statement aren't you missing the data type?  Have you tried using parameters.AddWithValue?

Comment: i thought the datatype since its text will default to the varchar of what's being passed in. It looks okay in the sql profiler.

Answer (score 2):

```
(
  (v.title = @banone) OR (vs.label = @banone) OR 
  (v.title LIKE @banone + ' %') OR (vs.label LIKE @banone + ' %')
)
...
@banone=N'BA'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The first two or cases have no reason to exist.  You'll capture the same records if you just use the LIKE cases.  For example:

`(v.title LIKE @banone + ' %') OR (vs.label LIKE @banone + ' %')`

where @banone='BA'

---

I think your parameter adding code isn't right.

This `parameters.Add("@" + key + "right",  val + " %");`

Should be `parameters.AddWithValue("@" + key +"right", val + "%");`

There are two things to note.  First I removed the space just prior to the percent sign.  Second, I'm using AddWithValue instead of a plain Add.

The question back to you then is whether or not that space was important.  Looking back at your original query, searching for `title = 'BA' or title LIKE 'BA %'` would actually ignore things where title had a value of *BAT* for example but would pickup a title like *BA Something*

You might want to post the data you are working with and the result you received.